# How to return fetch data in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I want to return my fetch data to an H2 in my ID - inspiration-container, my code doesn't currently work.  What am I doing wrong?  Please be specific and/or show full examples, as I'm very new to this.

```
    // get inspired event listener
    inspireBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    
      fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (response) {
     
        
          var responseContainerEl = document.querySelector('#inspiration-container');
    
          var inspireData = document.createElement('h2');
    
          inspireData.setAttribute('src', response.data);
    
          responseContainerEl.appendChild(inspireData);
        });
    
        });
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: I don't get an error in the console, but the quotes don't show up on my page

Comment: `h2` elements do not have a native `src` attribute that does anything. Please take some tutorials on JavaScript and HTML, and show what research you've done.

Comment: What do you expect `inspireData.setAttribute('src', response.data);` to do?  `response` is an array (from the JSON data), it does not have a `data` property.

Comment: I had used a similar syntax to return an image from a giphy api, and it worked fine.  I was trying to recreate this type of fetch (but for quotes, not images).  Clearly I don't understand it yet.  I can fetch, just don't have the JS skills yet to know how to do the return of the data properly.

Comment: First things first you need to check your response what is in that  what kind of data transfered your app. I saw that your response includes text() func. init .

Comment: @KellieWerrell Not every API is gong to return data in the same structure.  Try to add `console.log(response);` (before `var responseContainerEl`) to see what data you are getting.  You may need to loop over the returned array or process the data in some way to get what you want.

Comment: Thank you Deniz Firat, and Rocket Hazmat. I console logged the response successfully.  Deniz, with your example below, I was able to disect each piece of it and now understand how it works. A million thanks from this beginner!

Answer (score 1):

```
 // get inspired event listener
    inspireBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    
      fetch("https://type.fit/api/quotes")
        .then(function (response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          var responseContainerEl = document.querySelector('#inspiration-container');
          var t = document.createTextNode(response);
    
          var inspireData = document.createElement('h2');
    
          inspireData.appendChild(t);
    
         document.getElementById("inspiration-container").appendChild(inspireData);
        });
    
        });
```

First investigated whats in my response. After that i saw a text() function init. I returned response.text to get quote data.

After that created a TextNode to store my data.
By using the getElementById() rendered h2 tag to container called inspiration-container but these answer include only one h2 tag you can try to seperate them im not gonna do all of the work :).